# set image with device name when we do chat through bluetooth

Tags: android

Everybody know when we do chat through bluetooth it shows device name. Is it possible to set image with device name? I am using Eclipse. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: do you mean by programatically or inbuilt ?

Comment: AFAIK , it might not possible in inbuilt one

Comment: is it possible with programming?

Comment: ya, in programming you can create your own GUI for it and achieve it

Comment: first of all very thank for your time, can you give me any example if you have or sample code of this in which image is used

Comment: you welcome dear, see it is very simple, you can get any Bluetooth based demo application from that application, fetch code of Device Discovery & connection. now put this code in the activity where you want to do so, and you can put some image for a particular device connection.

Comment: ok lucifer i have a code, in this code i try image, thanks for your time

Comment: you welcome. keep sharing your knowledge.